# If p is a limit point of M prove that p must be a limit point from the left of M or from the right of M

Tags: analysis

So I know i need to use the definition of a limit point from the left which would be p is a limit point of (p-1,p) ∩ M
and also the definition of a limit point from the right which would be p is a limit point of (p,p+1) ∩ M.

However I am stuck on proving this formally.
If anyone has any insight on the a direct proof that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

What would it mean if there existed a $\varepsilon>0$ such that the cardinalities of $(p-\varepsilon,p)\cap M$ and $(p,p+\varepsilon)\cap M$ are both finite? How does this fit in with your definition of a limit point?